# How to disable uglify file renaming for a specific file in production build?

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

In my production build uglify breaks the linkage to a referenced file in my css, due to file renaming.  It seems there is a simple fix for this, but in my google search, I apparently missed it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The css file:

```
.priority_stars {
  background: url:('assets/images/star.gif') no repeat;
  ....
}
```

And as expected, uglify renames the file as expected. This breaks the linkage. Is there a simple way to get grunt to automatically rename this file.  This clearly is already taking place most every other type of file linkage in my build, just not in my css files.  How to tell the Gruntfile.js to do this?

Here is the Gruntfile.js (from the yo angular-fullstack framework):

```
// Generated on 2015-02-27 using generator-angular-fullstack 2.0.13
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var localConfig;
  try {
    localConfig = require('./server/config/local.env');
  } catch(e) {
    localConfig = {};
  }

  // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    express: 'grunt-express-server',
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
    injector: 'grunt-asset-injector',
    buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control'
  });

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: 'server/app.js',
          debug: true
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: 'dist/server/app.js'
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      injectJS: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'],
        tasks: ['injector:scripts']
      },
      injectCss: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
        ],
        tasks: ['injector:css']
      },
      mochaTest: {
        files: ['server/**/*.spec.js'],
        tasks: ['env:test', 'mochaTest']
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'karma']
      },
      injectSass: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['injector:sass']
      },
      sass: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.html',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
          '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      express: {
        files: [
          'server/**/*.{js,json}'
        ],
        tasks: ['express:dev', 'wait'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          nospawn: true //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.client %>/.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
          "jasmine": true
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc',
          "jasmine": true
        },
        src: [
          'server/**/*.js',
          '!server/**/*.spec.js'
        ]
      },
      serverTest: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc-spec',
          "jasmine": true
        },
        src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
      },
      all: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
      ],
      test: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.openshift',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/Procfile'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Debugging with node inspector
    'node-inspector': {
      custom: {
        options: {
          'web-host': 'localhost'
        }
      }
    },

    // Use nodemon to run server in debug mode with an initial breakpoint
    nodemon: {
      debug: {
        script: 'server/app.js',
        options: {
          nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk'],
          env: {
            PORT: process.env.PORT || 9000
          },
          callback: function (nodemon) {
            nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
              console.log(event.colour);
            });

            // opens browser on initial server start
            nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
              setTimeout(function () {
                require('open')('http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
              }, 500);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      target: {
        src: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.client %>/',
        exclude: [/bootstrap-sass-official/, /bootstrap.js/, '/json3/', '/es5-shim/', /bootstrap.css/, /font-awesome.css/ ]
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public'
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        ],
        // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
        patterns: {
          js: [
            [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
    // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat',
          src: '*/**.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat'
        }]
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      options: {
        mangle: false
      },
    },

    cssmin: {

    },

    // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
    ngtemplates: {
      options: {
        // This should be the name of your apps angular module
        module: 'tracker2App',
        htmlmin: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
        },
        usemin: 'app/app.js'
      },
      main: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
      },
      tmp: {
        cwd: '.tmp',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'assets/fonts/**/*',
            'index.html'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            'package.json',
            'server/**/*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        dest: '.tmp/',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
      }
    },

    buildcontrol: {
      options: {
        dir: 'dist',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        connectCommits: false,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
      },
      heroku: {
        options: {
          remote: 'heroku',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      },
      openshift: {
        options: {
          remote: 'openshift',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'sass',
      ],
      test: [
        'sass',
      ],
      debug: {
        tasks: [
          'nodemon',
          'node-inspector'
        ],
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
      },
      dist: [
        'sass',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },

    mochaTest: {
      options: {
        reporter: 'spec'
      },
      src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
    },

    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
      },
      chrome: {
        options: {
          args: {
            browser: 'chrome'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    env: {
      test: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test'
      },
      prod: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      },
      all: localConfig
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS
    sass: {
      server: {
        options: {
          loadPath: [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/components'
          ],
          compass: false
        },
        files: {
          '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    injector: {
      options: {

      },
      // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
      scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
              ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js']
            ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component scss into app.scss
      sass: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
            return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
          },
          starttag: '// injector',
          endtag: '// endinjector'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
            '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.{scss,sass}'
          ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component css into index.html
      css: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  });

  // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
  grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
    grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

    var done = this.async();

    setTimeout(function () {
      grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
      done();
    }, 1500);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
    this.async();
  });

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    if (target === 'debug') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:server',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concurrent:debug'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'env:all',
      'injector:sass',
      'concurrent:server',
      'injector',
      'wiredep',
      'autoprefixer',
      'express:dev',
      'wait',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
    if (target === 'server') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'mochaTest'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'client') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'autoprefixer',
        'karma'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'e2e') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'autoprefixer',
        'express:dev',
        'protractor'
      ]);
    }

    else grunt.task.run([
      'test:server',
      'test:client'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'injector:sass',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'injector',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'autoprefixer',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Could you post your gruntfile as well please?

Comment: Have done so, thansk!

Comment: It's definitely not uglify - uglify can only minify and combine javascript files. I believe the issue is related to a plugin called *rev* - just ensure that paths you specified in your config are correct - or remove it if you don't want to rename any files.

Comment: Thanks very much -- once I knew where to look -- it was easy to fix.  See the answer I posted.  So hopefully this will help someone else in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the post by Yauheni Leichanok I discovered that the issue was in the rev plugin and I was able to fix my issue by simply adding a pattern to usemin settings in the Gruntfile.js to also handle *.css files.  Here is the fix/adjustment to the Gruntfile.js:

```
          css: [
        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ]
```

Or showing it in context for clarity:

```
// Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
    ],
    // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
    patterns: {
      js: [
        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ],
      css: [
        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ]
    }
  }
},
```